# What is Spotlight on iPad – where are Spotlight icons displayed?

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode, spotlight

I'm developing a Universal iOS game with Xcode and I have to supply 3 images for icons.

1. An icon image for the home screen (app).
2. An icon image for iPad in Settings.
3. An icon image for iPad Spotlight.

I am wondering what "**Spotlight**" actually is (and where I can access Spotlight on my iPad), so I can work out where the icon will be displayed.

Comment: Could you edit in some context. Are you trying to understand Apple's App Store submission guidelines? If so use iTunes connect tag.  If you're trying to operate a specific iPad, please upload a screenshot of what you're trying to figure out

Comment: No, I'm asking on the iPad device, what is the iPad spotlight? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

**[Spotlight](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201285)** is the search function in iOS.

It can be accessed from the Home screen by swiping down.

From Apple Support:

> Use Search on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch
>   With iOS 9, Search lets you look for content from the web, your contacts, apps, nearby places, and more. Powered by Siri, Search offers suggestions and updates results as you type.
>
> There are two ways to use Search on your iOS device.
>
> #### Quick Search
>
> Drag down from the middle of the Home screen and type what you're looking for.
>
> #### Siri Suggestions
>
> Drag right from the Home screen to show search and get Siri Suggestions.